# how to copy folder\subfolder\files to program files directory with batch script inside the folder

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, vbscript

```
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM --> Check for permissions
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "amd64" (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\config\system"
) ELSE (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
)

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
set params= %*
echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params:"=""%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B

:gotAdmin
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"

xcopy "%CD%\Package\Contents\" -destination "C:\Program Files (x86)"
pause

=========================

C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\FL>xcopy "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\FL\Package\Contents\" -destination "C:\Program Files (x86)"
Invalid number of parameters
0 File(s) copied

C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\FL>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Question goes here**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118895/discussion-on-question-by-gary-doman-how-to-copy-folder-subfolder-files-to-progr).

Answer (score 1):

In your xcopy command, you need to remove the last backslash of the source path. Moreover, "-destination" is an invalid parameter.

Try something like that :

```
xcopy /S "%CD%\Package\Contents" "C:\Program Files (x86)"
```